# Как правильно отображать прогресс в консоли?

Tags: python, progress-bar

В моей программе имеются различные числовые значения, которые постоянно изменяются, мне требуется выводить их в консоль (`без использования GUI`). Самое простое - это выводить каждую отдельную строку на каждой итерации, но тогда она засоряет консоль, и читать не удобно. Пробовал очищать консоль через `cls||clear` - тоже не самый лучший вариант, потому что выводится все очень быстро, а задержки выставлять не хочется. Последнее, что я придумал - использовать `progressbar`, и тут тоже возникли проблемы (1 `progressbar` работает корректно, а если я пробую сделать их несколько, то они друг друга перекрывают, как я понял, это происходит из-за возврата каретки, может быть и нет). У меня есть значения, которые не имеют пределов (то есть нет границы, и они могут бесконечно увеличиваться или уменьшаться), я посчитал, что для этого подойдет `Counter`. Но также есть значения, у которых есть границы, например 0/100 - там я уже решил использовать обычный `progressbar`. В идеале, хотелось бы, чтобы все эти строки были поочередно расположены в консоли и работали параллельно. Вот то, что я пробовал сделать (далеко от истины):

```
import time
from progress.counter import Counter
from progress.bar import Bar

my_list = []
for x in range(1, 101):
    my_list.append(x)
val = 0

counter_ = Counter('Counter: ')

for item in range(0, 100, 5):
    counter_.next(item-val)
    val = item
    time.sleep(0.5)

counter_.finish()

bar = Bar('Gens', max=len(my_list))

for item in my_list:
    bar.next()
    time.sleep(0.2)

bar.finish()
```

PS Даже в отдельных потоках пытался сделать, но потом осознал, что это не самый умный ход)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

без лишних библиотек, используя только ASCII

```
def progress(value, total, i=0, j=0):
    # для отладки в pyCharm обязательно ставим в настройках дебага "Emulate terminal in output console"
    print("\033[%d;%dH" % (i, j)) # Так перемещаем курсор в нужную позицию
    percents = 100*value/total
    # и рисуем свой градусник
    print('[{}{}] {}%\n'.format(('█'*int(percents//10)),'░'*(10-int(percents//10)), percents))

import time
for i in range(1000):
    progress(i,1000) # по умолчанию позиция градусника (0,0)
    progress(1000-i,1000,1,0) # второй "обратный градусник" на одну строку ниже первого
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: специально в коде добавил необязательные параметры - позицию градусника. сейчас добавлю второй градусник в пример

Comment: Tatarincev, благодарю)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

Comment: А когда один из баров достигает конца выполнения, у вас не путаются строки выполнения?

Comment: @Effex Попробуйте `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`, он там приспосабливается как-то к разным терминалам.

Comment: @CrazyElf, хорошо, спасибо